# FFmpeg remap filter not found

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to stitch 360° pictures using the method described here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter#no1

here's the command I use :

```
ffmpeg -i 360_0008.JPG -i xmap_samsung_gear_2560x1280.pgm -i ymap_samsung_gear_2560x1280.pgm -lavfi remap out.png
```

and the error I get :

```
    ffmpeg version 2.8.6-1ubuntu2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-11ubuntu1) 20160311
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x18c4920] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, image2, from '360_0008.JPG':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 7776x3888, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, image2, from 'xmap_samsung_gear_2560x1280.pgm':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: pgm, gray16le, 2560x1280, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, image2, from 'ymap_samsung_gear_2560x1280.pgm':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: pgm, gray16le, 2560x1280, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x18c88c0] No such filter: 'remap'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Did I miss something? Or is there something missing in the ffmpeg packaged for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: `ffmpeg -filters` displays the list of available filters. My version (windows N-79000-g66edd86) does not have remap either.

Comment: I downloaded the latest windows build and remap filter is available now. Maybe your version is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this problem myself, the remap filter was introduced in ffmpeg 3.1 which oddly ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have the repos for by default, in order to get ffmpeg 3 working on ubuntu 16.04, follow this guide, it worked for me:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/09/install-ffmpeg-3-1-ubuntu-16-04-ppa/

Edit:

But basically, you'll want to put these into the linux terminal (I tested with 16.04 Ubuntu)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then I prefer to:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But keep in mind, as noted on the page there, certain programs may rely on old ffmpeg2 libraries, so you'll want to look into it as needed.

Hope this helps :)